# How do I avoid the "java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format" error while using JMeter 2.12

Tags: jmeter, gzip

I'm trying to record my interactions with a SAAS website using JMeter 2.12. I get the following error trace as soon as I try to login:

> java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
>       at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.http.client.entity.GzipDecompressingEntity.decorate(GzipDecompressingEntity.java:56)
>       at org.apache.http.client.entity.DecompressingEntity.getDecompressingStream(DecompressingEntity.java:68)
>       at org.apache.http.client.entity.DecompressingEntity.getContent(DecompressingEntity.java:82)
>       at org.apache.http.client.entity.GzipDecompressingEntity.getContent(GzipDecompressingEntity.java:41)
>       at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.getContent(BasicManagedEntity.java:89)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:348)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1141)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:236)
>   Blockquote

I searched for the solution and found one [in BugZilla: Bug 51918](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51918) where it says to turn off the concurrent download. I tried that by unchecking the "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" option in the 'HTTP Requests Defaults'- but still getting the error and cannot proceed.

Can anyone please help? Thanks a lot!
--Ishti

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I think I got an answer. Thanks to [Bhargav in his post](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Jmeter-EOFEXCEPTION-ERROR-WHILE-TESTING-SERVER-USING-PROXY-td5717694.html) where he basically told to change the 'HTTP sampler settings' (in the HTTP test script recorder) to 'Java'. I tried that and it's not giving me the error anymore. I can proceed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got into this problem in JMETER this week. The solution that worked for me in current version is.

In the header manager add:

Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=0,deflate,sdch

The server will send you a response that JMETER can handle.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on a Web application (Genexus WebApp) when it sent me an HTTP 403 error code with invalid encoding.

So to troubleshoot the problem I use two approaches:

1. First, turn on the log level to `DEBUG`, and enable the Log Viewer:

[image: debug level option]

With this we can see the current payload in the Viewer:
[image]

2. Another alternative is to set the `accept-encoding` to [`identity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding#directives), to receive the payload uncompressed.

[image: identity encoding configuration]

So after that, I figured out the problem was my request (invalid params)