# Jmeter 440 error code. How can I resolve this error?

Tags: jmeter, genexus

I am working with Jmeter and Blazemeter in a login script for a web made with Genexus.
The problem that I am having is in the POST.

Whenever I try to make a POST http petition, Jmeter throws the next thing:
[image]

As you can see, in the response body, I am having a 440 http error code. This is a login Time-out which means the client's session has expired and must log in again. I used to have a 403 error code but now, after doing some arrangements, I have 440. Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm not an expert on Genexus. All my findings are from a black-box point of view.

### Genexus Security

I found that Genexus requires at least two things to authenticate on Web Application (I tested only Java and .Net generated apps).

1. The `GXState` parameter. This param is sent in post request, and from my understanding works as "Synchronizer token pattern", see more info on [Cross-site request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention). We need to send this param on every post request.
2. The `gxajaxEvt` parameter. This is very specific to Genexus Apps. In the [documentation](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?9404,Stress%20Test%20Tips) mentions this parameter is send encrypted in the URL, and this behavior is managed by the "[Javascript debug mode property](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?17384,Javascript%20debug%20mode%20property)":

```sh
# Javascript Debug Mode: Yes
http://{server}:{port}/{webappname}/servlet/com.{kbname}.{objectname}?gxfullajaxEvt,gx-no-cache=1442811265833
# Javascript Debug Mode: No (default value)
http://{server}:{port}/{webappname}/servlet/com.{kbname}.{objectname}?64df96a2d9b8480aed416e470dae529e,gx-no-cache=1442811265833
```

### JMeter Script

1. So, to get the `GXState`, we can use the `Regular Expression Extractor`:
   [image: Regular Expression Extractor]

   Name of created variable: `GXState`

   Regular expression: `name="GXState" value='(.*?)'`

   Template: `$1$`

   Match No.: `1`

   Default Value: `NOT_FOUND`
2. The `GXState` is a JSON, object, from it we can extract the `GX_AJAX_KEY` to encrypt `gxajaxEvt` string. Note that, I found the `GX_AJAX_KEY` is the key used to encrypt in this case, but some others could apply. We can debug this using Browser Web Console, with this:

```js
gx.sec.encrypt("gxajaxEvt")
```

We'll see something like this:
`"8722e2ea52fd44f599d35d1534485d8e206d507a46070a816ca7fcdbe812b0ad"`

As we can found, all the client encryption code is in the `gxgral.js` file. Genexus uses the [Rijndael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) algortihm (Sub set of AES) with block size of 128 bits.

[image: Browser Web Console]

To emulate this client behavior in the JMeter Script we can use the "JSR 233 sampler". A way to get the Rijndael results is use the Bouncy Castle library. We need to add this jar [(bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.68)](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15to18/1.68/bcprov-jdk15to18-1.68.jar) to the JMeter's lib folder to use it.

Our code script will be something like this (Language Groovy 3.0.5/Groovy Scripting Engine 2.0):

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.util.Arrays
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.BufferedBlockCipher
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RijndaelEngine
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables

String gxState = vars.get('GXState')
String gxAjaxKey = JsonPath.read(gxState,'$.GX_AJAX_KEY')
byte[] input = Arrays.copyOf('gxajaxEvt'.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), 16)
RijndaelEngine engine = new RijndaelEngine(128)
KeyParameter key = new KeyParameter(Hex.decode(gxAjaxKey))
BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new BufferedBlockCipher(engine)
cipher.init(true, key)
byte[] out = new byte[16]
int length = cipher.processBytes(input, 0, 16, out, 0)
cipher.doFinal(out, length)
String encryptedOutput= Hex.toHexString(out)
log.info 'gx.sec.encrypt("gxajaxEvt")='+encryptedOutput
String gxNoCache = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
log.info 'gx-no-cache='+gxNoCache
vars.put('gxajaxEvt', encryptedOutput)
vars.put('gxNoCache', gxNoCache)
```

The script work like this:

- First, We get the previos `GXState` variable extracted.
- Second, Using JSON Path (Already [available in JMeter 5.4.1](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/c7279348335b820c35ee570462cb2e0b4eb1c370/lib/aareadme.txt)) extract the `GX_AJAX_KEY` property.
- Third, We apply the Rijndael algorithm over the `gxajaxEvt` using the `GX_AJAX_KEY` as a key.
- We also create the `gx-no-cache` to handle the cache.

[image: JSR233 Sampler]

3. With these variables we can send the next request successfully:
   [image: Next HTTP Request]

We can found this sample JMeter script available [here](https://gist.github.com/JuanMorenoDeveloper/29aaf0b0996b1e6b2a2816bd94d2d51e).

For complex scripts, please refer to [this guide](http://Building%20JMeter%20scripts%20with%20GXtest) (Requires GXTest)

In case we get this exception in JMeter ( `java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format`) please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66968483/4825845) too.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser

Answer (score 1):

Any [HTTP Status 4xx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors) is a **client error**, to wit you're sending an incorrect request.

If custom 440 [http status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) means "session has expired" my expectation is that you have a recorded hard-coded session ID somewhere in your request parameters or [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

You should carefully inspect previous response(s) and look for something which appears to be a session id, once you find it - [extract it using a suitable JMeter's Post-Processor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-tokens-and-session-ids-to-variables/) and replace hard-coded session ID with the appropriate JMeter Variable. The process is known as **[correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)**